# How many numbers $x$ less than $30030$ are there such that $30030$ divides $x^3-1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How would you tackle this problem? I am looking for hints. The things I have observed so far: $30030 = 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13$. So none of these prime numbers can divide $x$. This gets rid of a significant number of candidates but still leaves a merry number of them hanging.

**EDIT**: I didn't mention it but we are looking for positive solutions.

Comment: $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: One thing to note is that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. The factor $x-1$ can be divisible by any or none of those primes, but then $x^2+x+1$ must be divisible by the rest. I don't know how to use this to avoid a brute search, though.

Comment: @Arthur I had noticed that as well but it didn't lead me anywhere useful.

Comment: There are infinitely many such $x$, namely $x=1-30030k$ for all positive $k\in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think we're implicitly assuming $x$ to be positive here. Could be nice to get an explicit confirmation, though. (I personally think it's better to ask "is $x$ assumed to be positive?" rather than give an example exploiting what is probably a small oversight by the asker. It's a bit too passive-aggressive for my taste, most of the time.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm stating the question as it was given to me. It is meant as an exercise, not to be solved with a computer.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Which lecture is it you got this exercise? Combinatorics? Number Theory? What kind of result can we use to solve it? Reciprocity laws?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a competition problem (supposedly), so any result appropriate can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start. The Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that we can deal with each of the primes separately. Let's take some examples:

For the prime $2$ it is obvious that $x$ must be odd.

Modulo the prime $5$ the cubes are $0^3=0, 1^3=1, 2^3=3, 3^3=2, 4^3=4$ so we must have $x\equiv 1 \bmod 5$

Modulo the prime $7$ we find that $1^3=2^3=4^3=1$ so $\frac 37$ of the possibilities work modulo $7$.

See if you can work it out from here before you read on.

> Now the difference between $5$ and $7$ is that $7-1=2\times 3$ where $3$ is the power we are interested in. Modulo $7$ we have $x^6-1=0=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)$ (little Fermat) and there are three cube roots of $1$ rather than just the one.

With these clues you should be able to work it out (if in doubt try $70$ instead of $30030$ to start with)

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Without looking at the hint I painstakingly went through the calculations of each cube root mod p for p = 1,2,3,5,7,11,13. Then using the chinese remainder theorem and basic combinations we get $3\times 3$ solutions so $9$ integers total

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite For further thought, if you ever end up following these ideas further, you might note that there are three behaviours here. With some primes $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ remains the factorisation. Modulo $3$ we have $x^3-1=(x-1)^3$ - there is a multiple root (this is related to "ramification"). Modulo $7$ we have $x^3-1=(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)$ ("splitting").

Comment: I did a little bit today and I concluded that these are the only two possible behaviors possible if the the exponent is $3$. In fact the roots form of subgroup of the finite field, so we always need their size to divide the order of the finite field we're working over. In particular that explains why it will never split if $3$ does not divide $p-1$. I asked another question here on SO for some further direction of investigation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832587/roots-of-polynomial-over-finite-field-forms-a-group