# Roots of polynomial over finite field form a group

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

I was playing around with some polynomials over finite fields (specifically $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ where $p$ is prime), and I was wondering if there is in general a condition for the roots of a polynomial to form a group.

As an example, the polynomial that prompted the question was $x^3 - 1$. Playing around with the roots in different fields, I noticed that the set of solutions is always either $\{1\}$ or $\{1,k,k^{-1}\}$, which are obviously subgroups of the finite field we work in. It's easy to show that this is always true. Next came the generalization to polynomials of the form $x^q-1$ for any $q\in \mathbb{N}$, and it again it's fairly straightforward to show that their roots form a group.

However after investigating some more, it looks like I got lucky with those polynomials, as other ones I've looked don't have that nice structure in their roots. The base condition that already limits our choice quite a bit is that $1$ must be root, but I haven't found any more restrictions. What are some more examples of such polynomials and where could I learn some more about them?

Comment: I think the only examples are $x^m-1$ because the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic and so every subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: Chiming in with lhf. In fact, any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is easily seen to be cyclic. Also, if $G\simeq C_m$ is a cyclic subgroup of $K^*$, $K$ a field, then it is easy to show that
$$P_G(x)=\prod_{z\in G}(x-z)=x^m-1.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a multiplicative group structure on zeros (of a polynomial over some field $\Bbb{F}$) we necessarily need three conditions:

1) $1$ must be a zero.

2) Polynomial must be reciprocally symmetric; in other words $$p(z)=\text{constant}.z^{\text{deg}(p)}p(1/z).$$ (This condition guarantees that the existence of inverses)

3) If $a,b$ are zeros of $p,$ then $p(ab)=0.$
(This condition guarantees the closed-ness under multiplication)

When three conditions are satisfied, one can easily show that zeros of $p$ form a subgroup of the multiplicative group of some field extension of $\Bbb{F}.$

**EDIT:**
Here the fist condition is redundant as it can be deduced from other two conditions.
Also the third condition implies if $a$ is a zero then so does $a^2, a^3, \cdots.$ Since we have only finitely many zeros for a polynomial, this implies that there are $m, n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $a^m=a^n.$ Thus $a$ must be a root of unity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping for another family of polynomials that would satisfy these conditions. The conditions you give (except maybe for 2?) are more or less the group axioms adjusted for polynomials, which isn’t very interesting. That being said, is 2) necessary?

Comment: It is necessary and also not artificially made to answer your question. People have studied those polynomials for a long time. [see this as an example](http://www.norbertwiener.umd.edu/fft/FFT11/slides/Joyner.pdf).

Comment: In fact there is a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) for reciprocal symmetric polynomials.